# Ubuntu + qt, how to update?

Tags: c++, qt4

Installed qt from ubuntu software center then can't find examples with qml, checked version, it shows that Using Qt version 4.6.2 in /usr/lib.

My question, how to update qt creator and qt? 
Is there any button on qt creator or function in make or qmake to update from 4.6.x to 4.7.xxx?

If I will download new version from official site I will duplicate all that things as qt creator, linguist, assinstent and designer, and fear to be confused which version I using in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either update your ubuntu to 10.10 or 11.04 or use this ppa, which contains Qt 4.7.0

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu lucid main
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is some temporary solution and also will not give     up-to-date version. Latest version is qt4.7.2.

Comment: You can always use Qt SDK from  Qt homepage,if you want the latest version. Ubuntu 11.04 also contains 4.7.2. AFAIK, there's no official repo for the latest Qt, you can try your luck by searching the ppa though.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have `libqt4-dev` installed: `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`.

Then try: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: libqt4-dev already was installed, then tried next script, result was:
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded

Answer (score 0):

For everyone asked this question: the situation has been changed. Currently there is the [repository](https://launchpad.net/~forumnokia/+archive/fn-ppa) with the latest packages for Qt.

To add it, run: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:forumnokia/fn-ppa`